# Дата в формате hhmmss.ddmmyy

Tags: c++

Как сделать программу, которая создает переменную, которая будет равна "text.hhmmss.ddmmyy.txt"? 
Те решения что я находил имеют windows.h или выводят в формате Tue mmm dd hh:mm:ss yyyy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наиболее простым способом будет использование функции `strftime`:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
    char str[32];
    if (std::strftime(str, sizeof(str), "text.%H%M%S.%d%m%y.txt", std::localtime(&t))) {
        std::cout << str << '\n'; // выведет text.230954.211215.txt
    }
}
```

Как и в случае со всеми функциями Си, надо выбрать буфер подходящего размера.

С++ решение - это использование `put_time`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << "text." << std::put_time(std::localtime(&t), "%H%M%S.%d%m%y") << ".txt";
    std::string str = stream.str();
    std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

Также можно использовать другие библиотеки, например [Boost.DateTime](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/date_time.html).

Comment: Не компилируется. Второй способ тоже... test.cpp:5:31: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);

Comment: @DanielDash для первого варианта должно быть достаточно заменить `nullptr` на `0` или `NULL`. Чтобы обойтись без использования c++11.

Comment: @alexolut Действительно. Теперь работает...